# Canvas context "bezierCurveTo" has a bug under Chrome 16+ / Safari 5+

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, canvas, safari

If stroking a bezier curve whose last control point overlaps first point, the curve shape won't display on canvas; The sample code is as

```
    var cv = document.getElementById('cv'), cxt = cv.getContext('2d'),

//  4 points :  last point overlaps first point;
pts = [[100, 100], [400, 50], [350, 300], [100, 100]];

//  draw bezier curve
cxt.beginPath();
cxt.moveTo(pts[0][0], pts[0][1]);
cxt.bezierCurveTo(pts[1][0], pts[1][2], pts[2][0], pts[2][3], pts[3][0], pts[3][4]);

cxt.stroke();
```

I have asked in chrome-help forum before but never get any responses. Why no one notice this?  Is it a bug ??

As I haven't permission to attach image now, please check here for a live sample and you are definitely knowing what I am saying:
[Chrome canvas 'bezierCurveTo' bug](http://browser.zc0000.com/chrome-canvas-bezier-bug.html)

Comment: trying to catch the eye of Webkit developers ? :)

Answer (score 0):

This is hack, but you could apply little offset on one of the coordinates (x or y). In that case first and last points' coordinates will not be *exactly* the same and `Chrome` will draw the curve. Try something like this:

```
pts = [[100, 100], [400, 50], [350, 300], [100, 100]];

//....

cxt.moveTo(pts[0][0], pts[0][1]);
cxt.bezierCurveTo(pts[1][0], pts[1][1], 
                  pts[2][0], pts[2][1], 
                  pts[3][0], pts[3][1]+1e-5);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZcCNe/)

Comment: Thanks. Actually I know how to get around but just want to notice Chrome-team to fix the issue in some later versions.  I posted the issue to Chrome forum long ago but didn't get any response.

Comment: @zc0000 So in `stackoverflow`, you are looking for audience to support you for 'knocking the doors' of `Webkit` developers houses, I guess. :)